# Azure DevOps Common Branch Policy Build Pipeline for all Repositories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-repos

we are setting up Policies for our Org. One need we have is to have a build and annotation at every Pull Request with Sonarcloud. Is there a way to create a common ci build pipeline which will run at every PR, checking out the respective repo, detect the type of project (or read a manifest file or so) do the code analytics and build, annotates the PR?

So in the Azure DevOps repo you can create a common branch policy for all the master branches. I tried to use a standalone yaml pipeline but it never started when I created the pr. Can someone help me on the right track? Do I need to create a resource in the yaml? Is there any variable I can use from the PR to detect the repo and the branches?

Just for everybody to understand, you can create common branch policies and individuals.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer ? How did it go? You can [accept below answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add all the repositories in the resources section in the yaml because of the known issue reported in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/build-pipeline-definition-is-not-found-during-pr-b/1193244).

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: MyRepo
      type: git
      name: MyRepo
```

However, if you use a classic UI Pipeline in the `Build Validation` instead of the yaml pipeline. You donot need to add all the repositories in the resources section. But you need to skip the pipeline to sync the source: (Go pipeline edit page-->Click Get sources-->check Don't sync sources)

[image]

You can use the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to get the information about the pull request. See below:

```
$(Build.Repository.Name)
$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

Then you can run the git commands in a script task to check out the pull request branch. See below example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: MyRepo
      type: git
      name: MyRepo
pool: 
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- powershell: |
    
    git clone "https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name)"
  
    cd "$(Build.Repository.Name)"
    git fetch origin pull/$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)/merge:pr-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId) 
    # checkout pr branch
    git checkout pr-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

Note: you need to grant [build service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service) read permission for target repository

Comment: @mike0812 Could you manually queue your validation pipeline to see if it is successful? There might be something wrong with the pipeline.